# sqlite3 table fails to link to Access

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, odbc

I created a sqlite3 table and linked it to my 2016 accdb. In looking at the result I saw that I had neglected to add a particular column to the table, so I deleted the link, added the missing column to the table, saved it, and attempted to re-link it to Access. The table is displayed in the Access 'Link Tables' dialog, but when I select it and click OK the dialog closes but the table fails to link, with no error message displayed. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. An extraneous blank column was somehow inserted into the table. When I deleted it the table linked correctly.